# Reusing file -upload directive for two file input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having two input fields and using file upload directive to upload the files.But when i change the second file first file gets effected too.How to make both files work independently.

//html files

```
<div ng-controller="fileCtrl">
<input type="file" file-upload id="file1">
<input type="file" file-upload id="file2">
</div>

  //directive

 app.directive('fileUpload', function () {
  return {
    scope:{
        fileUpload: "="  
    }      
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.bind('change', function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files[0];
            scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[0] });
            }                                       
        });
      }
    };
  });


  //Controller
   $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {            
        $scope.files.push(args.file);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, what do you mean that the inputs would be independently? i ran your code and it's work as expected
do you mean that each input would have is own list inside the scope?

Comment: Hello Tom Mendelson.What i mean is that when uploading two files each input field should call different functions after the file is selected.When i give a condition if(file1!=null){function abc}if(file2!=null){function xyz}.But what happens is that after uploading the first file when trying to upload the second file since file1 also got some object info both functions are getting called.Hope i am clear in explaining.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understand what you are wishing for,
each directive should call another function
so, i added a param to the directive to recive a function (callback) that would be called when the file is changed. (by the way, using callbacks is much better, from performance to code design.

any way, your .js should look something like this:

```
app.directive('fileUpload', function ($parse) {
  return {
    scope: {
      fileUpload: '=',
      callback: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      el.bind('change', function (event) {
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        scope.callback({ file });
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('main', ($scope) => {
  $scope.files1 = [];
  $scope.files2 = [];

  $scope.functionA = (file) => {
    $scope.files1.push(file);
  }

  $scope.functionB = (file) => {
    $scope.files2.push(file);
  }

});
```

and your html should look like:

```
  <div ng-controller="main">
    <input type="file" file-upload callback="functionA(file)" id="file1">
    <input type="file" file-upload callback="functionB(file)" id="file2">
  </div>
```

i hope it meets your requirements

Comment: Hi Tom.I tried your logic but functionA and function B is not getting called when the file is selected.